# How to increase C stack size for R in ESS?

Tags: ess

I can not figure out how to change the C stack size for R in ESS. I can change it in terminal as follows:

```
X:~$ ulimit -s
8192
X:~$ R --slave -e 'Cstack_info()["size"]'
   size 
7969177 
X:~$ ulimit -s 16384
X:~$ R --slave -e 'Cstack_info()["size"]'
    size 
15938355
```

As suggested by an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit) on stackoverflow.

After restarting an R session in emacs (M-x R) I get the following:

```
> options(STERM='iESS', str.dendrogram.last="'", editor='emacsclient', show.error.locations=TRUE)
> options(width=113, length=99999)
> Cstack_info()["size"]
   size 
8284000 
>
```

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and ESS version 20150622.413. I'm wondering how to make the ESS interactive R shell pick up the new C stack size?

I have not found a way to set the C stack size within R and that is why I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps well overdue, but I had the exact same question. So in case there are others out there with this problem: simply set the stack size using "ulimit -s" in the terminal, and then call emacs from the terminal. Once you start R in ESS, you should see that your stack size has been adjusted.